# How to make an UIButton with emboss background image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uibutton

This is the effect of button on iPad Safari:
[image: iPad Safari]

Now I have only the icon file like that: 
[image: action icon]

How can I programmatically make an `UIButton` with the icon image as background look like the `Safari` on `iPad`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can set background image of uibutton or set background color of button.

Comment: what I want is the emboss effect.

Answer (score -1):

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
[btn setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

try this one..

Answer (score -1):

```
UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 30)];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ar.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

[image: bg.png] bg.png

[image: ar.png] ar.png